# git merge of two branches overwriting the customize code and latest build code

Tags: git, merge

I have scenario to merge to different app builds with git but its not working.

1- My repository have total 4 Branches
`master`
`dev`
`clean`
`update`

2- Brach creation process as follows:

create `dev` branch from `master` branch

create `clean` branch from `dev` branch

create `update` branch from `dev` branch

3- `Master`, `dev`, `clean` branch have same code my customize app code. now, i have a latest app build in zip form i just want to merge latest build with my previous customize code.

4- In `update` branch first i remove the previous code and add the latest build code and push it.

5- When i merge my `update` branch to `clean` branch its overwrite my custom changes that's should not happened. it should show conflicts of my customize code and latest build code for resolve but git merge both `update` and `clean` branch code without showing conflicts.

why git overwriting latest build `update` branch to my custom code `clean` branch without showing conflicts. Thanks

Comment: What commands are you actually running

Comment: Note that *branch names do not matter* in Git. All that matters is the *commit graph*. If you think a branch name means something, and therefore some code should only appear on one branch, or something like that, you're misunderstanding Git. We can't tell you much more without a [mcve].